# Define a type as array of a certain length

Tags: typescript

Is simpler way to define a type as an array of a certain type and length? I am looking to define the type as an array of 11 numbers and would like a little shorter than:

```
function someFunc(someVar: [number, number, number, number, number, number, number, number, number, number, number]) {
}
```

I have seen https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html defining `number[]` and `Array<number>`, but they don't allow to specify the length (`Array<number, 11>` would be great).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no simpler way.
You can either define a numbers array with no fixed size:

```
let arr1: number[];
//or
let arr2: Array<number>;
```

Or if you want a set length then you need a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) (which is what you're using now):

```
let arr: [number, number...];
```

When using tuples there's no way of specifying the number of elements other than explicitly specifying them as you did.

Comment: Boohoo. Cool. Thanks.